# mathematical expectation of length of dependency well.

Tags: pr.probability

We have these assumptions:

1. $W$ is a finite set
2. $\mathcal W$ is the set of all functions $f:W\to \mathcal P(W)$.
3. $p:\mathcal P(\mathcal W)\to [0,1]$ is a probability measure.

For each $w\in W$ and $m\in \Bbb N\cup\lbrace 0\rbrace$,
$$\rho(w,m)=p(\lbrace f\in \mathcal W : |f(w)|=m \rbrace)$$

Given $V\subseteq W$. What is the mathematical expectation of cardinality of the finite set:
$$V\cup\bigcup_{w_1\in V}{\left(f(w_1)\cup\bigcup_{w_2\in f(w_1)}   {\left(f(w_2)\cup\bigcup_{w_3\in f(w_2)} {\left(f(w_3)\cup\bigcup_{w_4\in f(w_3)} {\left(f(w_4)\cup... \right)} \right)} \right)}\right)}$$

in terms of $|W|$ and the $\rho(w,m)$?

---

edit:
I think the case when $p$ is uniform is enough for me.

---

edit2:
uniformity of $p$  is not enough. But we can assume $\rho(w,m)$ does not depend on $w$ instead.

Comment: Could you give a small example of what you have in mind here?  It's unclear (to me) how probability enters in.  In particular, if $W$ is a (specific) finite set and $f$ is a (specific) function, then it seems to me that $p(w,m)$ is either 0 or 1, depending on the number of elements in $f(w)$.

Comment: edited‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌.

Comment: Is the set (whose expectation of the cardinality you want to find) the same as $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty f^n(V)$$, where $f^n(V)=f(f^{n-1}(V))$ and `$f(V)=\{f(x):x\in V\}$`?

Comment: can be denoted by that. But not exactly. because $f:W\to \mathcal P (W)$ (not $f:W\to W$).

Comment: I fixed what I assume was a tiny typo (a $w_3$ that should have been a $w_4$).

Comment: @CC: Ah, that's right, one as to define something like $f(V)=\bigcup_{w\in V} f(w)$ instead.

Comment: Can you say something about why you want to know this? Do you have in mind an application where we only know the $\rho$ about some probability on that set of functions? And what is the meaning of that expectation?

Comment: Is that supposed to be the set of vertices reachable starting from an element of $V$? Again, how is $\rho$ used?

Comment: as an application. suppose you open this page: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/editors/bhl   then you open all links in that page in a new tab (or window) in you web browser. then you open the links in those new windows in separate tabs (with condition that you don't open a page that is opened already). Finally there will be no new links. and the process terminates. this is called dependency well. I want to calculate the expextation of number of opened tabs. this makes sense if one downloads a file from each page. there are also other applications for example in using a dictionary.

Comment: Your big displayed expression (the one with all the nested unions) defines a function $S(f,V)$ which takes values in the power set of $W$.  I think what you're asking about is the real valued function

$$E(V) = \sum_f p(f)|S(f,V)|,$$

where the sum is taken over the (finite) set of functions and $p(f)$ is the probability pre-assigned to $f$.  (There are $|W|^{2^{|W|}}$ functions $f$, so in the uniform probability case, $p(f) = 1/|W|^{2^{|W|}}$.)  But I don't see what it means to express this "in terms of $|W|$ and the $\rho(w,m)$."

Comment: (Note:  The little tower of exponents in my previous comment doesn't look right on my screen.  The exponent of $|W|$ should be $2^{|W|}$.

Comment: yes I think you're right. I think determining $|W|$ and $\rho(w,m)$ is more meaningful when I compare this model with real applications. for example in dictionary $|W|$ is the number of all words (it can be 100000 for instance). $\rho(w,m)$ is the expectation that you will encounter $m$ new words (ypu don't know their meaning) while reading the definition of the word $w$.

Comment: Ah, I think I see.  Let me distinguish two objects:  a *lexicon*, which is a list (or set) of words, and a *dictionary*, which is a list (or book, or set...) of *definitions* of the words in the lexicon, using (sometimes) words from the lexicon itself in each definition.  Your set $W$ is the lexicon, and your functions are abstractions from the set of all possible dictionaries for that lexicon.  You want to know how many definitions you're going to wind up reading, on average, if you start with a set of words $V$, pick up a dictionary at random,.... (continued in next comment)

Comment: (continued) ... and then look up every word you encounter, starting with the ones in $V$, that you don't know that dictionary's definition of.

Comment: exactly. start with a word, learn that words definition and the definition of all words you encounter (and you don't know their definitions) while reading the definitions. because the set of words isfinite this process terminates after a finite number of steps but how many steps is expected? However dictionary is just an example for this model.

Comment: Understood.  But the lexicon/dictionary example provides (for me, at least) clarity for the essence of the problem.

Comment: Incidentally, a "dictionary" well worth reading is Sid Gershgoren's *The Extended Words*, available at http://www.reddragonflypress.org/music/2053.  Gershgoren has invented a lexicon of roughly a thousand words, and gives definitions and usages for each.  Here, for example, is the entry for "Hiamate":  *A temporary freezing of thought during the solution of a mathematical problem or of any problem, forcing the thinking outward, ever outward, toward the "random ether of random discovery."*

Comment: seems someone is downvoting all questions on first page!

Comment: It seems to me that you can model this with (directed) graphs instead. To be precise, make the set of vertices be $W$ and you have an edge from $i$ to $j$ if $j\in f(i)$. Then you want to know the expectation of the size of "the set you can get to, starting on $V$".
This seems more natural to me. Unfortunately, either way I don't have a clue, unless we know more about the distribution of $f$ (or in this formulation of the edges)

Comment: To simplify the notation one can define $g:W\to mathcal P(W)$ by $g(w)=w\cup f(w)$. But about graphs, I don't know if anythig in graph theory can help to solve the problem.